# How to update values in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary D in python

Dictionary  is having a multiple elements and one is another dictionary
I want to update the  value of 'column_name' (if its nonempty) for the dictionary 'columns' with a backquote character

Case 1: 
    Original Dictionary:

```
{'table_name': 'table1', 'columns': {'data_type': 'string', 'column_name': 'data'}, {'data_type': 'bigint','column_name': 'foreign'}}
```

I want updated Dictionary as below :with column_name appended with backquote

```
{'table_name': 'table1', 'columns': {'column_name': '`data`'}, {'column_name': '`foreign`'}}
```

Case 2:

```
Original Dictionary: 
{'table_name': 'table1', 'columns': {'column_name': 'start'}, {'column_name': 'primary'},
 'table_name': 'table2', 'columns': {'column_name': ''user''}, {'column_name': 'order'}
 }
```

I want updated dictionary as below: (with column_name appended with backquote

```
{'table_name': 'table1', 'columns': {'column_name': '`start`'}, {'column_name': '`primary`'},
 {'table_name': 'table2', 'columns': {'column_name': '`'`user`'`'}, {'column_name': '`order`'}
```

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: your dictionaries have syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some deeper flaws with your dictionary structure, such as values included without a key, and I would recommend reading a good tutorial on dictionary structure and reference:

https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

For your base question, though, you would treat the value in the secondary dictionary as a value of the dictionary.

Given the following dictionary (edited to be a valid dictionary, I changed the columns to a list as I believed that was your intent):

```
dictionary = {'table_name': 'table1', 'columns': [{'data_type': 'string', 'column_name': 'data'}, {'data_type': 'bigint','column_name': 'foreign'}]}
```

You would address the 'data_type' value in the first column of the list of columns as follows:

```
dictionary['columns'][0]['data_type'] = value
```

However, just a strictly nested dictionary given this example (only one column, so it doesn't need to be nested in a list):

```
dictionary = {'table_name': 'table1', 'columns':{'data_type': 'string', 'column_name': 'data'}}
```

You would address the 'data_type' value in the columns dictionary:

```
dictionary['columns']['data_type'] = value
```

Comment: Thanks everyone ,below code worked. I am using for loop to handle this as per Davids suggestion and I went ahead and wrote it

Comment: #Case2
for count in range(len(listofdict)):
        for x in listofdict[count]:
            if isinstance(listofdict[count][x], list):
                for i in range(len(listofdict[count][x])):
                    listofdict[count]['columns'][i]['column_name'] = 'updated value'

Comment: #Case 1: Single dictionary     
for x in dict:
        if isinstance(dict[x], list):
           for i in range(len(dict[x])):
                dict['columns'][i]['column_name'] = 'updated value'